# How to apply 'keyframes' css to a specific class in React Component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react component called `ComingSoon`. This is a component of other components of my React application.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../Styles/ComingSoon.css';

class ComingSoon extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="comingSoon-container">
                    <span className="comingSoon-text1">Coming</span>
                    <span className="comingSoon-text2">Soon</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ComingSoon;
```

This is my CSS for that component with filename `ComingSoon.css`:

```
.comingSoon-container {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}

.comingSoon-container span {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
}

.comingSoon-text1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    animation: text 3s 1;
}

.comingSoon-text2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #2b8bc6;
}

@keyframes text {
    0% {
        color: white;
        margin-bottom: -60px;
    }
    30% {
        letter-spacing: 30px;
        margin-bottom: -60px;
    }
    85% {
        letter-spacing: 12px;
        margin-bottom: -60px;
    }
}
```

How do I make sure the CSS style of `@keyframes text` doesn't apply to other components of my application and just apply to this specific component for contents with className `comingSoon-container`.

Comment: the "text" in `animation: text 3s 1` selects the `@keyframes text` ... so, only something with class including `.comingSoon-text1` would use those keyframes - so, unless you observe something different, there shouldn't be an issue ... you could have `.comingSoon-container .comingSoon-text1 { animation: text 3s 1}` if there's a chance that you use `.comingSoon-text1` outside of `.comingSoon-container` I guess

Comment: Thanks, the word `text` is a common class name. So as long as I rename the word `text` in both locations, it should work properly right?

Comment: text isn't a class name, `.text` would be, but class names are not used inside a CSS property value - it's a "animation-name" that refers to a keyframes "keyframe-name" - so, has nothing to do with class name (which would be `.text` anyway)

Comment: also, I take it `text` is a common class name *in your code* - because, it's not generally - in all my CSS in dozens of projects, I never once use the class name `text` - I really can't see why I ever would